# Problema com LEFT JOINs joins e uma condição

Tags: sql, query, join

Tenho este problema há já algum tempo. Conto com a vossa ajuda.

Tenho 3 tabelas:

```
publicacao
id  cartaz          titulo
1   eradogelo.jpg   A Era do gelo
2   ojogo.jpg       O Jogo
3   helpme.jpg      Help Me
4   please.jpg      Please
5   6words.jpg      6 Words
```

Armazena o leitor e a publicação que foi favoritada (gostou):

```
favorito
id  from(id do usuário)  to(id da publicação)
1   74                   2
2   74                   3
```

Armazena o leitor e a publicação que ele já leu:

```
leu
id  from(id do usuário) to(id da publicação)
1   74                   2
2   74                   3
3   74                   5
```

Agora, selecione todas as publicações e me diga (assinale) quais o usuário (74) favoritou e quais ele leu.

Query:

```
SELECT
    p.id,
    p.cartaz,
    p.titulo,
    case when isnull (f.id) then 'não' else 'sim' end AS favorito,
    case when isnull (l.id) then 'não' else 'sim' end AS leu
FROM publicar AS p
LEFT JOIN favoritos as f ON p.id = f.to
LEFT JOIN leu as leu ON p.id = l.to AND f.`from` = 74
ORDER BY p.id
```

Resultado:

```
id(da publicação) cartaz          titulo         favorito  leu
1                 eradogelo.jpg   A Era do gelo  não       não
2                 ojogo.jpg       O Jogo         sim       sim
3                 helpme.jpg      Help Me        sim       sim
4                 please.jpg      Please         não       não
5                 6words.jpg      6 Words        não       não (deveria ser "sim")
```

Se ele leu e não favoritou(gostou) ambas as colunas vem com o "não". Gostaria que ajudassem nisso, por favor.

Comment: Coloque o texto no lugar da imagem e também descreva o problema/resultado esperado.

Comment: A questão é: quando o usuário lê alguma publicação e não gosta (ou não põe aos seu favoritos) a resposta se leu ou não a publicação surge sempre igual à resposta do favorito. Como está na tabela acima.Por favor, analisem as tabela.

Comment: Tem um erro `leu as leu ON p.id = l.to` deveria ser `leu as l ON p.id = l.to`. Se quer usar um alias tem de o definir, assim como está o **l** não é nada. Além disse tente não dar nomes de campos iguais ao nome da tabela.

Comment: Me distraí um pouco. Já está resolvido. Obrigado @Jorge B!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O filtro por usuário precisa estar em ambos:

```
LEFT JOIN favoritos as f ON p.id = f.to AND f.from = 74
LEFT JOIN leu as leu ON p.id = l.to AND l.`from` = 74
```

Comment: tem ainda outro problema, `leu as leu` deveria ser `leu as l`.

Comment: Obrigado @luciorubeens, está a funciona com esta dica. Vlw cara.